# Trying to recreate this semi circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, vector

I've been trying to recreate this semi circle for the past couple of days. But i'm having trouble on where to start.

I've created a semi circle. But what i need is how do i add the dots (smaller circles).

Any help is much appreciated!

[image: Semi Circle]

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="npsbar"></div>
  <span>0</span>
  <span>10</span>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
 
  position: relative;
  
    #npsbar {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 20px;
        
    &:nth-child(2) {
      bottom: 0;
      left: 25px;
    }
  }
}
```

JS

```
let bar = new ProgressBar.SemiCircle(npsbar, {
  strokeWidth: 10,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: 'tomato',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: null
});
 
bar.trail.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');
bar.path.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');

bar.animate(0.8);
```

Comment: could you share your currrent state please

Comment: It's basically what you're seeing but without the circles at the end and no numbers or text.

Comment: @Shaydx sure, just add your SVG markup to your question

Comment: Give me a moment please i'm on mobile on my way home! I'll add what i have in a short time. Thanks!

Comment: https://codepen.io/npstoday/pen/GRZmaaL - Okay, so what i have is as said very simple. Just the basic and i'm using Progressbar.js to make the SemiCircle. But if there is a better way i'm all ears. - I just can't wrap my head around how i would begin with the other smaller circles.

Comment: @RobertLongson Sorry about that. I've added the markup in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert background line into the balls with this CSS:

```css
{
stroke-width: 10;
stroke-dasharray: 0 14; /* <-- if you change this 14 to any other value, you can change the number of "balls" */
stroke-dashoffset: 4;
}
```

So for your ProgressBar library it will be:

```js
bar.trail.setAttribute('stroke-width', '10');
bar.trail.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', '0 14');
bar.trail.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', '4');
```

Example: https://codepen.io/antoncodepen/pen/vYGmqOP

Comment: @Shaydx you're welcome. Just approve the answer (only if it is ok for you), so it will go away to the history =)

Comment: Quick question. The stroke-dasharray gets cut in half. If i want to only have 10 circles. Is there a way around that? So i get 10 full circles. Tried with some css but nothing really changes.

Edit: It works with overflow. but is there a better way perhaps?

Comment: @Shaydx not really until you can control the SVG, but you can't because you use library. It redraws SVG not you. Take a look on the other answer by "Rubix Overflow". He just recreated the SVG, adding 2 circles inside.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this,

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
svg{
  height: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  fill: none;
}
svg path{
  stroke: #ffc23b;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
    <path d="M 50,50 m -45,0 a 45,45 0 1 1 90,0"></path>
    <rect fill="#fff" height="50" width="50" x="81" y="18"></rect>
    <circle cy="50" r="5" fill="#c9c9c9" cx="95"></circle>
    <circle r="5" fill="#c9c9c9" cy="35" cx="93"></circle>
    <circle r="5" fill="#ffc23b" cy="21" cx="84.5"></circle>
    <use xlink:href="#one"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```